# How to restrict displaying paginator only in Header or Footer in YUI?

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

How to restrict displaying paginator only in Header or Footer in YUI with out using any extra div tag? By default it is being displayed both at the top and bottom of the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the containers config for your Paginator.  This would require that you have a container in the DOM for the DataTable and one for the Paginator.

Alternately, the generated DOM for the paginator containers is uniquely id'd, so you can just use CSS to hide whichever one you don't want to see ala display:none. Use FireBug or the inspector in your browser of choice to see the id/class that you want to target.